# I am unable to save my Token once I get it from the API call

Tags: c#, xamarin

I am learning as I create, that being said, I have spent quite a few hours on JUST the login/register pages in the app I am trying to make.

I have finally got to the point where I am able to make the API call to get the response back with the information I need.

I just don't know how to save the token once it comes back.

I am using SQLite for local storage, and I have a "Token" nclass to save it to, but I can't figure out how to actually save it and continue forward.

(I could be completely wrong and it doesn't work at all, but that's all part of learning, I guess.)

anyways, here is my Token class

```
 public class Token
    {
        [PrimaryKey]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string accessToken { get; set; }
        public string errorDescription { get; set; }
        public DateTime expireDate { get; set; }
        public int expireIn { get; set; }

        public Token() { }
    }
```

and here is my APIServices class (some stuff is commented because I am working with my buddy to get everything sorted on the API side)

```
public class ApiServices
    {
        public string JsonResult { get; private set; }

        public async Task<bool> RegisterUserAsync(string email, string name, /*string first_name, string last_name,*/ string password)
        {
            var client = new HttpClient();

            var model = new RegisterBindingModel
            {
                Email = email,

                //FirstName = first_name,

                //LastName = last_name,

                Name = name,

                Password = password,
            };

            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model);

            HttpContent httpContent = new StringContent(json);

            httpContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");

            var response = await client.PostAsync("https://myurl/v1/auth/register", httpContent);

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(JsonResult);
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }

        public async Task<string> LoginAsync(string email, string password)
        {
            var keyValues = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
            {
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("email", email),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", password),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "password")
            };

            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "https://myurl/auth/login" + "Token");

            request.Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(keyValues);

            var client = new HttpClient();
            var response = await client.SendAsync(request);

            var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            JObject jwtDynamic = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(content);

            var accessTokenExpiration = jwtDynamic.Value<DateTime>(".expires");
            var accessToken = jwtDynamic.Value<string>("access_token");

            //Settings.AccessTokenExpirationDate = accessTokenExpiration;

            Debug.WriteLine(accessTokenExpiration);

            Debug.WriteLine(content);

            return accessToken;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets explain it step by step:

1.Install the `sqlite-net-pcl` package([Nuget URL](https://www.nuget.org/packages/sqlite-net-pcl/)). This package will help you to work with database in an easy way.

2.After installing it successfully, You need to add the using statement of SQLite to your class:

```
using SQLite;
```

3.In order to make a request to database, you will need to first make a connection to database. to do so, you need to declare a variable for aforementioned goal:

```
var db = new SQLiteConnection (dbPath);
```

4.Once you have the database connection object, you are ready to make requests to database. for example to save an object of type Token class, just do this:

```
var tokenInfo= new Token();
tokenInfo.accessToken="...";//set value to other properties like this

db.Insert(tokenInfo);
```

These are all you need to do an `Insert` request to database!

You might want to read more about aforementioned package in these urls: 
https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/data-cloud/data-access/using-sqlite-orm

Comment: This was amazing, I really appreciate you explaining it step by step. I had to do a little more digging, but you sent me in the right direction and helped tremendously. Thanks!